# Help to compose the script correctly

Tags: unity

Good afternoon. I have a problem: creating a color setting for the car. I created several Primary game objects, hung my own color on each one. I wrote a simple script, with 6 buttons, each button activates its Primary. There are no errors in the console, but changing colors does not work. I do not know what the reason is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ColorSettings : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Car;
    [Header("ColorSettings")]
    public GameObject Primary1;
    public GameObject Primary2;
    public GameObject Primary3;
    public GameObject Primary4;
    public GameObject Primary5;
    public GameObject Primary6;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Primary1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Primary2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    
    public void Color1Button()
    {
         Primary1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
         Primary2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         Primary3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         Primary4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         Primary5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         Primary6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void Color2Button()
    {
         Primary1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         Primary2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
         Primary3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         Primary4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         Primary5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         Primary6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void Color3Button()
    {
        Primary1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Primary4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void Color4Button()
    {
        Primary1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Primary5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void Color5Button()
    {
        Primary1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary5.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Primary6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void Color6Button()
    { 
        Primary1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Primary6.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

[image]

[image]

I made changes to the script, but now there is a problem again. Game objects are activated only after restarting the script
[image]

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of your scene? Have you tried hooking up the scripts to the buttons in anyway?

Comment: I'm going to take a screenshot now

Comment: I am not sure what the last two screenshots are supposed to show us. What could actually be interesting would be a screenshot of the inspector of the object with the above script.

Comment: The Color buttons 1 .....6 are responsible for changing the color.
In the script, they activate game objects

Comment: Code should always be shared as text, never as an image. You should also show where you call the `ColorButton` function from.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried controlling the color change with a switch statement or if?
and bool, maybe your program needs a way to verify if a color was selected and what to do when it is?
also make sure you linked the right buttons for the job, especially if you use the new unity system input is slightly different then the old one

Answer (score 1):

Your code is excessively verbose, and this is likely to lead to unexpected behaviours when copy-pasting the same script with minor changes. You can take advantage of data structures and loop statements to manage your GameObject activation/deactivation, and make your logic more flexible and less error-prone.

#### Storing GameObjects

You can define your colour presets as an array rather than individual elements:

```
public GameObject[] Primary;
```

The Inspector will let you expand the entries and assign the GameObjects of interest:

[image]

The advantage of having your GOs stored in an array is that you can use indices to access them, e.g. `Primary[3]` is your fourth object in the array (array indices start at 0).

#### Activating GameObjects

Since you have the same number of elements and buttons, you can just enable the GO of interest when the corresponding button is pressed. This can be achieved by knowing the GO index and looping through all GOs:

```
public void ColorButton(int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Primary.Length; i++)
    {
        Primary[i].SetActive(i == index);
    }
}
```

Here `index` is an arbitrary value you pass as an argument. The function loops through all objects and sets as active only the one whose position in the array is equal to the `index` (`i == index` returns `true`), while deactivating all others (`i == index` returns `false`).

#### Binding the UI to the activation logic

To make the above function work on button click, you can select a Button and add an entry to its *On Click ()* event in the Inspector. Then, drag the GameObject that has got your colour management script. Finally, look for the function defined above:

[image]

The input field below the function name is the value of `index` you want to pass as an argument when the function is triggered. You can change this value with different values for other buttons.

Each button will invoke the function with a different `index` value, and the `ColorButton()` function will take care of activating/deactivating the corresponding GameObject you assigned.

Comment: writes an error

Comment: Assets\Scripts\ColorSettings.cs(15,9): error CS0106: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item

Comment: @AlexGin it sounds like you pasted this code into the wrong part of your class file. Make sure it's inside the curly braces `{}` of the class, and not inside the curly braces of any other member nested within that class.

Comment: checked it out. I didn't find any errors

Comment: The problem is exactly what I told you it was. You put `public void ColorButton` inside `private void Awake()`. You cannot nest methods this way. `public void ColorButton` must be **outside** the curly braces of the `Awake()` method. Also, it is not appropriate to edit revisions to your question into someone else's answer. Edit your question instead.